# how to fix 'the connection was reset' issue in typo3 9.7.5 after installation

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

i'm setting up typo3 version 9.5.7 in my local server(php 7.2). successfully installed in my local server but after the installation i cannot login admin panel.

```
'sv' => [
        'packagePath' => 'typo3/sysext/sv/',
    ],
```

i just put this code to packagestates.php file. that time its work but if i reload the back end page the above code will automatically removed from packagestates.php site and connection was reset error message occurred .I am new in typo3 ,please help me

Answer (score 0):

The core extension `"sv"` in the part of the `PackageStates.php` you posted seems to be this one: https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms-sv

Did you set up the typo3 composer based? see: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/QuickInstall/Composer/Index.html

If it is automatically removed by TYPO3 after you reload, it means that there must be an issue with that sysext. Can you confirm that it actually is available in that folder?

Also note that the `PackageStates.php` only lists active extensions.
See: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.1/Important-73041-PackageStatesIncludesOnlyActivePackages.html?highlight=packagestates

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code snippet at the end of file "XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf" worked for me.

```js
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>

ThreadStackSize 8388608

</IfModule>
```